# Conditional Statement in Raster Calculator ArcMap

Tags: arcgis, conditional-statements, raster, arcmap

I'm trying to write a conditional statement in the raster calculator using the "con" tool, but it keeps arriving at an error:

"Runtime error SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression (,line 5)"

I'm trying to perform the following scenario:
If Fault_Risk is zero, then the output is simply the Bedrock_Risk, but if the Fault_Risk is non-zero, the result is a weighted equation 0.75x(Bedrock_Risk) + 0.25x(1+(Fault_Risk-1)/7).

My expression in the raster calculator is the following:

Con("Fault_Risk"=0, "Bedrock_Risk", 0.75*"Bedrock_Risk" + 0.25*(1+("Fault_Risk"-1)/7))

Any suggestions or obvious errors?
Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have a assignment expression instead of a comparison there. Should it be `"Fault_Risk"==0 ` maybe?

Comment: Thank you. That answered the error and allowed the calculation to run!

Comment: You may not be aware but there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcGIS for Desktop questions already answered.